# How to run two different animation in react- native one by one?

Tags: react-native

I want to implement animation in my react native app. I have created the animation but facing difficulty to manage these according to my requirement.

I want to show animation one by one.

Here is the video link for animation currently showing in my app :-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzwqpbkp6fqi8qw/SLXG5627.MP4?dl=0

In this video both animation working parallel, so I want to manage them one by one, like first animation complete then second will run.

Here is the code that I have written for that :-

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
        this.animatedValue1 = new Animated.Value(3);
        this.animatedValue2 = new Animated.Value(300);
        this.state = {
            userData: getUserDetail(),
            vouch_height: new Animated.Value(30),
            vouch_width: new Animated.Value(30),
            startSecond:false,
            startFirst:true,
            startFirst:false
        }
    }


animation() {
        this.animatedValue.setValue(0)
        this.animatedValue1.setValue(3)
        this.animatedValue2.setValue(300)

        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.parallel([
                Animated.timing(
                    this.animatedValue,
                    {
                        toValue: 2,
                        duration: 2500,
                        useNativeDriver: false
                    }
                ),
                Animated.timing(this.animatedValue1, {
                    toValue: 0.3,
                    duration: 2500,
                    useNativeDriver: false
                }),
                Animated.timing(this.animatedValue2, {
                    toValue: 50,
                    duration: 2500,
                    useNativeDriver: false
                })
            ])
        ]).start()
    }

 
animation1() {
        this.state.vouch_height.setValue(30)
        this.state.vouch_width.setValue(30)
        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.parallel([
                Animated.timing(
                    this.state.vouch_width, // The animated value to drive
                    {
                        toValue: 50, // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
                        duration: 150, // Make it take a while
                        useNativeDriver: false,
                    },
                ), // Starts the animation
                Animated.timing(
                    this.state.vouch_height, // The animated value to drive
                    {
                        toValue: 50, // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
                        duration: 150, // Make it take a while
                        useNativeDriver: false,
                    },
                )
            ]),
            Animated.parallel([
                Animated.timing(
                    this.state.vouch_width, // The animated value to drive
                    {
                        toValue: 30, // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
                        duration: 150, // Make it take a while
                        useNativeDriver: false,
                    },
                ), // Starts the animation
                Animated.timing(
                    this.state.vouch_height, // The animated value to drive
                    {
                        toValue: 30, // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
                        duration: 150, // Make it take a while
                        useNativeDriver: false,
                    },
                ),
            ])
        ]).start()

    }
```

Here is the render method :-

```
render() {
        const { thumbnailSource, source, style, ...props } = this.props;

        return (
            <Modal
                animationIn='fadeIn'
                animationOut='fadeOut'
                style={styles.modalContent}
                isVisible={this.props.isVisible}
                flex={1}
                justifyContent='center'
                alignItems='center'
                backdropOpacity={0.0}
                hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
            >{this.props.isVisible ? <>
                {this.animation()}
                <View style={{ top: 50, height: this.props.viewHeight + 50, width: windowWidth, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)' }}>

                    <Animated.View
                        useNativeDriver={true}
                        style={{
                            height: 300,
                            width: 300,
                            backgroundColor: "white",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            borderRadius: 150,
                            opacity: this.animatedValue1,
                            transform: [
                                {
                                    translateY: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
                                        inputRange: [0, 1],
                                        outputRange: [0, 250]
                                    })
                                },
                                {
                                    scaleX: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
                                        inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
                                        outputRange: [1, 0, 0],
                                    })
                                },
                                {
                                    scaleY: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
                                        inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
                                        outputRange: [1, 0, 0],
                                    })
                                },
                            ],
                            shadowColor: "#000",
                            shadowOffset: {
                                width: 0,
                                height: 9,
                            },
                            shadowOpacity: 0.9,
                            shadowRadius: 40.35,

                            elevation: 19,
                        }}
                    >
                        <FastImage style={[
                            styles.imageStyle,
                        ]}
                            source={this.props.img}
                            resizeMode='cover' />
                    </Animated.View>
                </View>
                {this.animation1()}
                <Animated.View style={{
                    position: 'absolute', top: global.vouchIconPossision.y,
                    width: this.state.vouch_width,
                    height: this.state.vouch_height,
                    margin: 0,
                }}>
                    <global.UserImg />
                </Animated.View>
            </> : null}
            </Modal >
        )
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong, can anyone please suggest me ?

Comment: Your desired behaviour would be that `animation1` runs after `animation`?

Comment: yes @dianaqqq, first animation() call then after animation1() will call

Comment: Ok, for the purpose of testing if that's your desired behaviour, try to put inside `animation1` a `setTimeout`; `animation1() { setTimeout( () => {...everything that's inside your function now}, [2500])`

Comment: I did try settimeout. delay, wait everything but not get fixed that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove Animated.parallel, and use just Animated.sequence

```
Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(
            ... 
        ),
        Animated.timing(
            ... 
        ),
    ]).start()
```

Comment: I did that, but not helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
call 2nd animation in "start()" as callback.

Change first method like this.
animation(callbackAnimation) {
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0)
    this.animatedValue1.setValue(3)
    this.animatedValue2.setValue(300)

    Animated.sequence([
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(
                this.animatedValue,
                {
                    toValue: 2,
                    duration: 2500,
                    useNativeDriver: false
                }
            ),
            Animated.timing(this.animatedValue1, {
                toValue: 0.3,
                duration: 2500,
                useNativeDriver: false
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.animatedValue2, {
                toValue: 50,
                duration: 2500,
                useNativeDriver: false
            })
        ])
    ]).start(callbackAnimation())
}

Then call it like this
animation(animation1);
```

Comment: Yes tried this as well, but not fixed yet